# Como decodificar isso?

Tags: python

Não consigo decodificar essa hash, preciso decodificar ela para realizar uma atividade do meu curso, alguém ai pode ajudar?

Já tentei decodificar em Md5, SHA1 etc..

Serei eternamente grato se alguém ajudar ❤️❤️❤️

Hash : JJ2XG5BAMEQHEZLNNFXGIZLSEB2G6IDVOBSGC5DFEB2GQZJAONSXE5TJMNSXGCSTN5WHSZD3II2HGM27GMZF6M3OMMYGIMLOM56Q====

Comment: A conversa se estendeu e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139848/discussion-on-question-by-vitor-como-decodificar-isso)